# How to use a Shopify Section across a Layout?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a section with content that can be edited from the Shopify Customizer. I use this section across multiple pages, but the content remains the same.

Is there a way to instead bind this section to a whole layout?

Because when you update the content, you have it re-enter it on every single page template that uses this section. I can have static HTML across all page templates that use a layout, but this isn't useful because the content needs to be editable from the Shopify Customizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a section across a layout after all.

I was doing

###### layout/my-new-layout.liquid:

```
{% render 'section-component.liquid' %}
```

when I was supposed to be doing

###### layout/my-new-layout.liquid:

```
{% section 'section-component.liquid' %}
```

##### For reference

If you're trying to convert a template-only section to a layout-only section...

1. Remove the section JSON data from the template: *templates/page.your-template.json*.
2. Add a `{% section 'your-section' %}` in the layout (i.e. *layout/my-new-layout.liquid*).